# Power BI templates with Snowflake data source

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a set of users using Snowflake who have been provided different databases but tables with the same schema.

I would like to create a Power BI template with “Snowflake” as its data source. When a user opens that template he should enter his server name, username, password details to [connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-snowflake) with his Snowflake account. The dashboard’s data model(schema) will be the same.

Upon checking [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-templates#using-templates), I see that the user can upload a different excel file in the same schema to reflect that dashboard with that uploaded file. Likewise, I need the support for the Snowflake data source to be reflected with the server name, user name, and password listed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

This option is not there in the Power BI.

That is the reason we have RLS - Row level security to filter the data based on the access provided.

If are asking for dynamic server connection, we cannot do that in Power BI.